# Check if a value is rotationally symmetric in Java

Tags: java

I was recently asked this question in a phone interview. Given a value, check if its rotationally symmetric or not. Rotational Symmetry means, if we write that number on a page and rotate that page by 180º, the number remains same.
I answered with the below solution and wanted to know if there's a better way to do this. Thanks!

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Rotational_Symmetric {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        HashMap<Character,Character> numbers = new HashMap<>();
        numbers.put('0', '0');
        numbers.put('1', '1');
        numbers.put('6', '9');
        numbers.put('8', '8');
        numbers.put('9', '6');

        System.out.println(isRotationallySymmetric(numbers,"0891680")); //true
        System.out.println(isRotationallySymmetric(numbers," ")); //true
        System.out.println(isRotationallySymmetric(numbers,"169")); //false
        System.out.println(isRotationallySymmetric(numbers,"8")); //true
        System.out.println(isRotationallySymmetric(numbers,"5")); //false
    }

    //to check if a value is rotationally symmetric
    //consider example "0891680"

    public static boolean isRotationallySymmetric(HashMap numbers, String input){
        if(input == null || input.equals(" ")){
            return true;
        }

        if(input.equals("2") || input.equals("3")||input.equals("4") 
                || input.equals("5") || input.equals("7")){
            return false;
        }

        char[] charInput = input.toCharArray();
        int start = 0;
        int end = input.length()-1;
        while(start<end){
            if(charInput[start] == (char)numbers.get(charInput[end])){
                start++;
                end--;
                continue;
            }
            else{
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ is better for this kind of question.

Comment: Swap all characters in the input with their rotated counterpart (e.g. 6 for 9, 9 for 6), and reverse the string; if there are any numbers without a rotated counterpart, it's not rotationally symmetrical. If the swapped/reversed string is equal to the input, it's rotationally symmetrical.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind next time @poixen  :)